# Call parent model field m2m relationship field from child

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to call the list of `M2M` object referenced in `ModelB` from `ModelC`.

I normally use it the other way around (start with parent model and filter down to child), but this time I cant see a way around it.

I feel there might be something to do with the related name, but the behaviour seems different than with normal FK.

Any ideas?

**models.py**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="title",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    ModelB_Field1= models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, blank=True)
    
class ModelC(models.Model):
    ModelC_Field1= models.ForeignKey(ModelB,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='modelc_field1')
```

**views.py**

```
def function(request, modelc_id):
    q = ModelC.objects.filter(pk=modelc_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelC is a secondary model that is linked via the ForeignKey field to the primary ModelB. To get the fields from the primary model, you need to use the ModelC_Field1 field.

```
ModelC.objects.get(pk=modelc_id).ModelC_Field1
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting the object from a model, can get the M2M field's all objects with `_set.all()`

Try this out

```
def function(request, modelc_id):
    q = ModelC.objects.get(pk=modelc_id).ModelC_Field1_set.all()
```

Comment: Hi there, thats the answer I tried previoulsy, but I am getting `'ModelC' object has no attribute 'ModelC_Field1_set'`. I tried with both the field name nad the related name. Any suggestion?